# Atomic swap in a cross compatibility zone setup

Tags: corda

I am pretty new to corda and I am curious if it is possible to do a cross compatibility zone DvP. According to https://www.corda.net/2017/08/compatibility-and-upgrades/ it is possible to have different corda newtorks in a global network.

My question addresses following use case: 
let's say I have two corda networks (compatibility zones). Each network has its own notary, nodes, customers & KYC process and is supporting a certain asset.
The first network provides for example a payment infrastructure and the second network a securities network.

Is it possible to do that by using R3 corda, if yes is there any example/tutorial?

Thanks in advance for any support!

Comment: Hi there. I just published this paper to the corda-dev mailing list that relates to this topic... take a look and let me know what you think? https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/topic/a_short_paper_on_the_nature/23388372?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,23388372

Comment: Sorry - hit post too soon..!  The other point I was going to make is that a corda network (aka CZ) is intended to enable HUGE NUMBERS of applications/business networks to coexist... so the vision is that you would have payments and securities and syndicated loans and loads of other stuff all on the same CZ... but with each app/business network being used/being open to only subsets of the nodes on the CZ.   In other words, the idea is that there are very few CZs but each has LOTS of applications.

Comment: Hi Richard, thx a lot for your quick response! I will take a look at your paper. Ok I see, but is it still possible to have different networks operated & governed by different entities and allow for example a cross network DvP?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes but I think we're talking at cross-purposes :)   Networks operated and governed by different entities are intended to form and operate WITHIN a compatibility zone.

The way I think it's most helpful to think of Compatibility Zones is to imagine the concept just doesn't exist... imagine there was just ONE Corda network (ie CZ) that everybody used (that was transparently/openly governed so no one firm/group of firms controlled it)... and then all the different apps and business networks existed within it... able to interoperate and transact across each other, because their nodes were compatible... they would understand and accept each other's transactions, etc.

Think about it from the perspective of a firm installing a blockchain node: getting onto any blockchain network (a Corda CZ or whatever the equivalent concept is for other platforms)... getting an identity, punching the right holes in the firewall, setting up the node infrastructure...  it's analogous to the work needed to get a firm "on the internet" - setting up routers, getting IP addresses, etc, etc.

It's the kind of thing you want to do once and then reuse ruthlessly.  The idea that you would have to connect to an entirely new communications network for each app your firm used would be ludicrous.  And yet that's how some people seem to think blockchain deployments should be:  ie for each app, you set up a *separate* blockchain network with its own nodes and settings and identity layer and consensus providers.  But that's surely just nonsense, right?

You want to connect to a global network once and then reuse that infrastructure.

So the idea is that we try to have as few CZs as possible and encourage as many business networks as possible to form *within* that small number of CZs.

I know this can mess with your mind when you first hear about it because all the other enterprise blockchain platforms are going in totally the wrong direction (in my opinion..!)  They seem to be encouraging the formation of a separate private network for each application. But that just seems crazy to me.

So maybe try this: even if you think I'm mad, play along with the idea for a day or so and see if it begins to grow on you :)   If not, let's debate it again but I really do think this idea of multiple apps on the same overall shared network (ie multiple business networks in a single compatibility zone) is just so amazingly powerful as a concept.

So to your answer: can you do cross-app/cross-business-network DvP within a CZ?  Yes!  That is one of the key use-cases we invented Corda to solve... it's almost perfect for those sorts of scenarios.

Could you do it if the two apps were on different CZs? Well, yes... but it would be like asking if you could do DvP between assets managed in different databases or hosted on different blockchains.. it's just messier...  needing locking and 2PC and all the stuff that we can just eliminate if we hold ourselves accountable for not creating needless balkanisation/siloed deployment through deployment of standalone networks unless they're really, really needed.